# Unable to record jmeter script for flutter app

Tags: flutter, jmeter

Started recording scripts for flutter app in jmeter. I am able to record static files(images) but not the api calls. What would be the issue? 
PS -  All the settings are fine from mobile to system.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you cannot record API calls because they're being made using [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) which cannot be simply intercepted by JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder.

- iOS:

  - Transfer JMeter's self-signed certificate onto your device, the certificate is `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` and it's being generated in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation when you start [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
  - Under `Settings > General > About > Certificate Trust Settings` enable `Enable full trust for root certificates` for the JMeter's certificate
  - More information: [Trust manually installed certificate profiles in iOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204477)
- Android:

  - Copy JMeter's self-signed certificate onto your device
  - Follows steps from [Recording Using Android Devices](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285357-Recording-Using-Android-Devices) and [Network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#network-security-config) articles to enable trust for custom certificates for your application

Comment: Tried all these before itself, but not able to record it!!